# Display review rating in woocommerce in another format ( only number )

Tags: woocommerce, rating

I want display only number of review rating in review listbwith this WooCommerce  function display review rating in comment list:

```
function wc_get_star_rating_html( $rating, $count = 0 ) {
    $html = '<span style="width:' . ( ( $rating / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%">';

    if ( 0 < $count ) {
        /* translators: 1: rating 2: rating count */
        $html .= sprintf( _n( 'Rated %1$s out of 5 based on %2$s customer rating', 'Rated %1$s out of 5 based on %2$s customer ratings', $count, 'woocommerce' ), '<strong class="rating">' . esc_html( $rating ) . '</strong>', '<span class="rating">' . esc_html( $count ) . '</span>' );
    } else {
        /* translators: %s: rating */
        $html .= sprintf( esc_html__( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong class="rating">' . esc_html( $rating ) . '</strong>' );
    }

    $html .= '</span>';

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_star_rating_html', $html, $rating, $count  );
}
```

Now, when selected rate then sent review in review list , I would like display **ONLY NUMBER** of rated by user.

For example: when select 3 star an submit review  then in review list instead 3 star displayed text like You selected 3 Star .